# Serial interface via UDP sockets in C

Tags: c, serialization, serial-port, udp, serial-communication

I am new to serial interfacing and my company has asked me to design an API that configures a gyroscope -connected to a WIFI chip- using a C code, by sending the hex commands over a UDP socket to the WIFI chip. I made sure to adhere to the format provided by the manufacturer's manual but it seems that i am missing something when it comes to the serial interfacing aspect. I am using this code to do so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "port.h"
#include <time.h>

void waitFor (unsigned int );

unsigned char head1 = 0xff; //head
unsigned char head2 = 0xaa;  //head2
unsigned char saveadd = 0x00; //saveconfig address
unsigned char savevalue = 0x00; //save config  0x01 is factory reset
unsigned char endd = 0x00; //end

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;  /* our address */
    struct sockaddr_in remaddr; /* remote address */
    remaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");
    remaddr.sin_port = htons(8889);
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(remaddr);        /* length of addresses */
    int recvlen;            /* # bytes received */
    int fd;             /* our socket */
    int msgcnt = 0;         /* count # of messages we received */
    remaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    /* create a UDP socket */

    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("cannot create socket\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* bind the socket to any valid IP address and a specific port */

    memset((char *)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(myaddr));
    myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(SERVICE_PORT);

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        return 0;
    }



        printf("waiting on port %d\n", SERVICE_PORT);


        // Hex command that turns a builtin LED on
        unsigned char comPart1 =    0xFF;
        unsigned char comPart2 =    0xAA;
        unsigned char comPart3 =    0x1b;
        unsigned char comPart4 =    0x00;
        unsigned char comPart5 =    0x00;

        unsigned char commands [5]; /* unsigned char array to hold command */
        commands [0] = comPart1;
        commands [1] = comPart2;
        commands [2] = comPart3;
        commands [3] = comPart4;
        commands [4] = comPart5;




        unsigned char temp_buf [2]; /*buffer used to send hex command*/
        temp_buf [0]= (unsigned char) 0x00;
        temp_buf [1]= '\0';



        for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) 
        {
           temp_buf [0] = commands[i];

        if (sendto(fd, temp_buf, sizeof (temp_buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, addrlen) < 0)
            perror("sendto");
       }

        waitFor (0.5); /*delay specified by user manual*/



        printf ("%s \n", "Now saving the configration");
        //save commands as specified by user manual 
        unsigned char saveConfig [5];

        saveConfig [0] = head1;
        saveConfig [1] = head2;
        saveConfig [2] = saveadd;
        saveConfig [3] = savevalue;
        saveConfig [4] = endd;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
        {

        temp_buf [0] = saveConfig [i];

        if (sendto(fd, temp_buf, sizeof (temp_buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, addrlen) < 0)
            perror("sendto");
            waitFor (0.05);
       }
       waitFor (0.45);



}

void waitFor (unsigned int secs) {
    unsigned int retTime = time(0) + secs;   // Get finishing time.
    while (time(0) < retTime);               // Loop until it arrives.
}
```

I was able to configure the gyroscope serially (if disconnected from the WIFI chip and connected to a USB-TTL) using ***CuteCom***. So i know that the hardware works. What am I missing when it comes to serial interfaces. How would one go about achieving such a task?

Comment: "How would one go about achieving such a task?" - Learning the basics, reading datasheets and writing the required code. After all, this is **your** job and this is no tutoring or code-writing service. You want to read [ask]. Feel free to ask a **specific** question within site-rules, though.

Comment: @Olaf thanks for your feedback. my question is "What am I missing when it comes to serial interfacing". I adhered to all the specifications provided by the manufacturer but it's not working. Clearly its a serial interfacing issue. And i do not wish anyone to write any code for me, my code is already written. Just need guidelines

Comment: I don't know anything about your wi-fi gyroscope, it looks like you are sending a sequence of 5 datagrams, each containing 2 bytes (1 byte from the command plus 1 byte of zeroes).

Comment: "serial interfacing" and sockets are two very different things. The code you presented uses sockets but you tested with CuteCom using a comm port (or serial port). Are you sure your device is configured properly for socket communications?

Comment: @IanAbbott yes sir! I am essentially trying to send the following:
0xff 0xaa 0x1b 0x00 0x00 one byte at a time. Do you think the NULL (byte of zeros) are causing the issue? How would I indicate the end of the buffer if I am not to use it?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes i am positive, I was able to receive and stream data from the device using the recvfrom function. The Rx of the device is connected to the Tx of thw WIFI chip, so whatever i send thru the socket should go straight thru to the device. The configuration works for CuteCom but not thru code for some reason

Comment: "I am essentially trying to send the following: 0xff 0xaa 0x1b 0x00 0x00". Looks like to me you are sending 0xff 0x00 0xaa 0x00 0x1b 0x00,, etc. The 0x00 byte isn't a magical/universal end-of-buffer byte. There must be some protocol the gyroscope is using, maybe a defined message size, or a maybe a byte sequence that signifies end-of-message. This should be in the documentation. It would be great if you could capture the serial traffic to see exactly what is being sent via CuteCom. Also, make absolute certain the WIFI is connected the way you think it is.

Comment: You are setting the length of each datagram (the 3rd parameter of `sendto`) to `sizeof (temp_buf)` which is 2. If you want to send a single byte per datagram, set the parameter to `1`. What happens if you send the whole 5 byte command in a single datagram, e.g.: `sendto(fd, commands, 5, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, addrlen)`?

Comment: @yano it worked!! thanks I didnt know that. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks again

Comment: @IanAbbott My hardware doesnt accept the full buffer. It has to receive one hex at a time. Actually thats why i have a sequence of delays in between each hex in saveConfig. If its too fast it wont work. Thanks thought.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.
for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`  Then you will get a sizeable list of of warnings from the compiler.  For fixes, since parameters `argc` and `argv` are not used, the appropriate signature for `main()` is `int main( void )`  There are also several unused variables.

Comment: The parameter for the function: `time()` is either `NULL` or the address of a variable with type `time_t`  The `0` is an iffy fit for NULL,  Strongly suggest make the parameter `NULL`

Comment: the return type from function: `time()` is `time_t`, not `unsigned int`   All the associated variables (and parameters) of the function: `waitfor()` should be `time_t`

Comment: The posted code, in calling the function: `waitfor()` is passing a literal parameter of `0.45` (a doulble) however, the expected parameter type is `unsigned int`,  so the value being received in the parameter is 0.  Definitely not what you want

Comment: please post the contents of the file `port.h`

Comment: the function: `memset()` expects its' first parameter to be of type `void*` so casting it to `char *` is an error,  Best to not cast at all

Comment: the function: `time()` returns whole numbers (a count of seconds).  Since the code actually wants to wait only .45 second, much better to use this function: `int usleep(useconds_t usec);` and eliminate the function: `waitfor()`

Comment: returning a `0` generally indicate success.  What I expect the code should return, when there is an error, is `EXIT_FAILURE`, as defined in stdlib.h.   Therefore , suggest using `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` when an error occurs

Comment: in general, when discussing/referencing a socket, the usual name is not `fd` but rather `sock`.  Such usage of `sock` makes the code much easier to read/understand

Comment: why is the posted code only sending one byte at a time rather than the whole command?  A UDP socket can fail and over 6 separate messages, it could fail on any one of the messages.  Strongly suggest sending the while 6 bytes, so when a failure occurs the receiver does not get out-of-sync with the sender.   On a related subject, is the receiving device expecting a NUL byte after every byte in the command string?

Comment: I notice the remote device is hard coded to a dynamic DNS address on the local network.  Is that a good idea or is that the only address the remote device can respond to?

Comment: Which gyro chip are you trying to communicate with?

Comment: @user3629249  
1) This is a portion of a larger code. I didnt wanna include the whole thing just to make it easier to debug. I narrowed down my issue to piece of code. And i will def keep an eye out for warning next time!
2) As for the wait for function. I changed that to 'usleep()' which takes microseconds instead
3) port.h literally only contains a variable that holds the port number. I should've not included it.
4) I will try to follow naming conventions also.

Comment: @user3629249
5) I am dealing with a hardware that only accepts one byte at a time. Thats why i have a sequence of delays when sending the saving command.
6) The device only communicate on one IP address. Which actually have to be set it through a web interface by users. so it never changes unless i changed it.
7) I am using the JY-901 gyroscope.
Lastly, Thanks so much for your feedback, I am still learning and these tipswill def help me get better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you said/asked in the comments

> I am essentially trying to send the following: 0xff 0xaa 0x1b 0x00
>   0x00 one byte at a time. Do you think the NULL (byte of zeros) are
>   causing the issue? How would I indicate the end of the buffer if I am
>   not to use it?

From your code, however, you are sending a NULL byte in-between each of these data bytes.  `temp_buf` contains 2 bytes, you are hard-coding the second byte to `\0` and setting the first byte to the data byte.  Then the `sendto(fd, temp_buf, sizeof (temp_buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, addrlen` line sends the contents of this buffer.  If you trapped your network traffic in wireshark, you would see that you are sending `0xff 0x00 0xaa 0x00 0x1b 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00` rather than what you intended to send.

To answer your questions, `c` strings aside, there is nothing universal about a NULL byte terminator for a buffer.  Valid data bytes can be 0x00 all the time.  If I email someone a black picture, I'll be sending a whole stream of 0x00 bytes.  Your gyroscope must have some kind of protocol that should be described in its documentation.  In my experience, this has been a fixed message length, a start/end sequence of "magic" bytes, or even an application-defined header.  In your comments, you indicate the gyroscope simply wants one byte at a time, so there you go, just send it one byte at a time!  I imagine you changed your code to something like the following:

```
// really no need for temp_buf
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
{
  if (sendto(fd, &saveConfig[i] /* or saveConfig+i */, sizeof(char), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, addrlen) < 0)
  {
    perror("sendto");
    // I'm guessing from your indentation you want this wait inside the if-statement. Note that in the code you posted, the if-statement doesn't have any brackets so this will execute each time through the loop whether there is an error or not
    waitFor (0.05);
  }
  waitFor (0.45);
}
```

In general, any time you're dealing with network problems like this, I would strongly recommend using wireshark (or equivalent) to see exactly what you are sending,, it is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

`saveConfig` is binary data but you need to send the *hex* representation so:

```
temp_buf [0] = saveConfig [i]
```

will not work.

What you need is something like:

```
unsigned int
gethex(unsigned int val,int shf)
{

    val >>= shf;
    val &= 0x0F;
    val = "0123456789ABCDEF"[val];

    return val;
}

temp_buf[0] = gethex(saveConfig[i],4);
temp_buf[1] = gethex(saveConfig[i],0);
```

Comment: Thats a good way of doing it. There was no issue in data representation. It was a matter of how the data was propagated. Thank you!